# Django User form extension with email, first name and last name

Tags: django, forms, userform, django-1.4

Edit: there wasn't any mistake, this code works.

I am using django 1.4.5, My form is not displaying all the fields I want:

My code is the following:

```
class MyRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password1', 'password2')

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(MyRegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']

        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

It's only displaying the username, email and passwords.

Comment: Can you post the UserCreationForm code

Comment: It's a class imported from django.contrib.auth.forms. You can see the code in [github](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/auth/forms.py)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I tested this quickly just by initializing the form and printing it out to the terminal I copied your form code exactly and called as follows.

```
myregform = MyRegistrationForm()
print myregform
```

This return the following response in terminal

```
<tr><th><label for="id_username">Username:</label></th><td><input id="id_username" maxlength="30" name="username" type="text" /><br /><span class="helptext">Required. 30 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.</span></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_email">Email:</label></th><td><input id="id_email" name="email" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_first_name">First name:</label></th><td><input id="id_first_name" maxlength="30" name="first_name" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_last_name">Last name:</label></th><td><input id="id_last_name" maxlength="30" name="last_name" type="text" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_password1">Password:</label></th><td><input id="id_password1" name="password1" type="password" /></td></tr>
<tr><th><label for="id_password2">Password confirmation:</label></th><td><input id="id_password2" name="password2" type="password" /><br /><span class="helptext">Enter the same password as above, for verification.</span></td></tr>
```

As you can see the first_name and last_name is displaying so my best guess would be that it has something to do with your template processing code. Maybe if you could also post that here I can have a look.